# AutoMapper - Assign a value manually depending on the value of the source

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, dto

I would like to assign a value manually to a DTO property in the Profile of the AutoMapper depending on the value I have in my entity.

Below you can see my code, but it doesn't work as expected because the `.AfterMap` is independent from the `.Condition`, as a matter of fact every `dest.Sent` is mapped with `true`:

```cs
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.Sent,
    opts => opts.Condition(src => src.Status == 2 && src.Status != 1)
)
.AfterMap((notification, dto) =>
    dto.Sent = true);
```

My DTO

```cs
public class NotificationItemDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Sent { get; set; }
}
```

My Source

```cs
public class Notification
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to assign a value to `dest.Sent` which is a bool depending on `src.Status` which is an `int`. So if `src.Status == 1`, my `dest.Sent` = `false`, if `src.Status == 2`, my `dest.Sent` = `true`. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood the [usage of `.Condition()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html#conditional-mapping).

> AutoMapper allows you to add conditions to properties that must be met before that property will be mapped.

Hence, from your scenario, you are trying to **assign a different value** to the destination based on condition but **not block the mapping** from source to destination by condition which is the main purpose of `.Condition()`.

While `.AfterMap()` is the last action to be executed after the mapping definition logic is executed, hence the value will be overridden.

---

Using `.MapFrom()` and defining the logic to set the destination's `Sent` is `true` only when the source's `Status` is 2.

```cs
CreateMap<Notification, NotificationItemDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Sent,
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Status == 2)
    );
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6EdtqN)